# Return explicitly or implicitly?

Tags: java

Consider the following two code examples:

**1.**

```
void foo(boolean cake) {
    if (!cake)
        return;

    // TODO some work.
}
```

**2.**

```
void bar(boolean cake) {
    if (cake)
        //TODO some work.
}
```

Which one is the most readable/ semantic correct? With the first example you avoid additional indentation on the below code.

Should one return right away when there is no cake or not?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887212/shall-i-use-guard-clause-and-try-to-avoid-else-clause

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Usually you get the advice to avoid multiple exit points in a method. However the reasoning behind this rule is only valid if you have **long** methods - and then you have more to worry about than exit points.

Make your methods **short**, then make them even **shorter**. After this you can use whatever exit style you want, because it will be readable either way.

I came to this conclusion myself, but good books like [*Clean Code*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132350882) by Robert C. Martin will tell you the same.

Answer (score 20):

It depends on your intent. Your code should use idioms to match what its actually trying to do.

```
void foo(boolean cake) {
    if (!cake)
        return;

    // TODO some work.
}
```

Indicates that `!cake` is a precondition and as such is insignificant to what the function is doing.

```
void bar(boolean cake) {
    if (cake)
        //TODO some work.
}
```

Indicates that cake is an important part of what the function is doing.

Answer (score 5):

The first approach is what's called a guard. See [this article](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/flattening-arrow-code.html) by Jeff Atwood.

> Replace conditions with guard clauses. This code..
>
> ```
> if (SomeNecessaryCondition) {
>     // function body code
> }
> ```
>
> .. works better as a guard clause:
>
> ```
> if (!SomeNecessaryCondition)
> {
>     throw new RequiredConditionMissingException;
> }
> // function body code
> ```